# Proving that $\text{Var}(X)\cdot\text{Var}(Y)\geq\text{Cov}(X,Y)^2$ for real-valued random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Consider nondegenerate real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ with finite mean and variance. We can prove the inequality
$$\text{Var}(X)\cdot\text{Var}(Y)-\text{Cov}(X,Y)^2\geq0$$
in a variety of ways:

(1) We can recognize left-hand side as the determinant of the variance-covariance matrix of the random vector $(X, Y)$, and then invoke the fact that variance-covariant matrices are positive semidefinite.

(2) The variance and covariance are invariant under shifting by a constant, so by mean-centering $X$ and $Y$, the inequality reduces to $E(X^2)E(Y^2)-E(XY)^2\geq0$, which follows from [Cauchy-Schwarz for random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367973/proof-of-analogue-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-for-random-variables).

(3) We can try to prove the inequality “directly” by unraveling the left-hand side as

$$\big(E(X^2)-E(X)^2\big)\big(E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2\big)-\big(E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)\big)^2$$

which upon simplifying gives (if I haven’t made an error)

$$\color{blue}{E(X^2)E(Y^2)-E(XY)^2}+\color{red}{2E(XY)E(X)E(Y)-E(X^2)E(Y)^2-E(Y^2)E(X)^2}$$

According to the argument in (2), using shift-invariance of variance and covariance, the red term should vanish, but I’m not seeing why. What algebraic cleverness am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made no error in your calculations. However, you have misinterpreted the implication of shift invariance. It's not that the red term vanishes, but rather than if you replace $X$ and $Y$ in the blue portion with $X-\mathbb EX$ and $Y-\mathbb EY$ respectively, then when you simplify it out you will be left with the red and blue expressions together.

By the way, whenever $\textrm{Var}(Y)\not=0$ one has
$$
\textrm{Var} (X)\cdot \textrm{Var} (Y)-\textrm{Cov}(X,Y)^2=\frac{\textrm{Var}\bigl(\textrm{Var}(Y)\cdot X-\textrm{Cov}(X,Y)\cdot Y\bigr)}{\textrm{Var}(Y)}.
$$
I think this fits the bill of a "slick algebraic proof" of the type you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes, duh. This is what happens when I think at 3am. But still I wonder how to argue directly that the entire expression (blue and red terms together) is positive. There must be some clever quadratic manipulation, right?

Comment: Your question boils down to asking for a clever quadratic manipulation proof of the cauchy-schwarz inequality. Here it is: expand $\mathbb E\bigl((\mathbb EY^2) X - (\mathbb E XY) Y\bigr)^2$ and you get $(\mathbb EY^2)\bigl(\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EY^2-(\mathbb E XY)^2\bigr)$ after simplifying.